# Getting handle of externally running visible windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, external, hwnd

The problem is that, I want to get handles of all visible windows. Up to now I have achieved to get hwnd of a window which includes a substring. Here is my code. The block i have mentioned is in the comment, but i couldn't find any method to check the visibility of a window.

Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<HWND> asd,myVector;
HWND temp;

BOOL CALLBACK addToVector(HWND hwnd, LPARAM windowName)
{
    myVector.push_back(hwnd);
    //to get desired windows filtering by window name as substring
    /*

    TCHAR windowTitle[512];
    if (GetWindowText(hwnd, windowTitle, 512))
    {   
        if (_tcsstr(windowTitle, LPCTSTR(windowName)) != NULL)
        {
            myVector.push_back(hwnd);
        }
    }
    */
    return true; 
}

int main() 
{
    char substring[] = "chrome";
    EnumWindows(addToVector, (LPARAM)substring);

    cout << myVector.size() << endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine if a window is visible by calling [`IsWindowVisible()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
if(IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
{
    myVector.push_back(hwnd);
}
```

Comment: Upps thank you, and also I added one condition
if(IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && GetWindowText(hwnd, windowTitle, 512)).

Comment: You can add the comparison in there too `if(visible && getname && comparename) { ... }`